# Convex combination of nonnegative matrices, simplicity of second largest eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, spectral-radius

Let $\lambda_i$ denote the eigenvalues of the matrix $B$ and let $\rho(A)$ and $\rho(B)$ denote the spectral radii of the matrices $A$ and $B$, respectively. Suppose that $A,B$ are nonnegative matrices (a matrix with every entry $\geq 0$) with $$\rho(A) < \lambda_2 < \lambda_1 = \rho(B)$$ where $B$ is a rank-$1$ correction of $A$, in other words, $\operatorname{rank} (B-A) \leq 1$. In the problem it is known that $\lambda_1$ is simple. What I'd like to affirm is that exists a value of $s^*$ close to $1$ such that $A_s = A + s(B-A)$ has a simple eigenvalue (presumably the one strictly closer to $\rho(B)$, i.e $\lambda_2$, since then I'd like to replace $B$ with $s^*$).

I don't think the problem is true in general since with $B$ a multiple of $A$ doesn't seem true. In this setting I also have that the characteristic polynomial of $A_s$ is the convex combination of that of $A$ and $B$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @user8675309 edit: a matrix with entries $\geq 0$. Also, I do know Rouchè Theorem but if you could expand I'd be happier. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @user8675309 This is the article I'm studying https://www.researchgate.net/publication/277679399_Rank-One_Corrections_of_Nonnegative_Matrices_With_an_Application_to_Matrix_Population_Models I think I can't share it

Answer (score 0):

It is straight-forward to prove the  weaker claim that after perturbing  $s$, if needed, we may take $\lambda_2$ to have odd degree.  It may be possible to tweak the argument in the two paragraphs below to include derivative information of $p_s$ and get to a case of $\lambda_2$ being simple.  However as the final paragraph makes clear, this is unnecessary when one is familiar with winding number basics from complex analysis like the Argument Principle.

---

Where $\lambda_i$ are roots of characteristic polynomial $p_1$ (which the authors define so as to be monic)  and $\lambda_1$ is the biggest positive root and is already known to be simple and $\lambda_2\gt \rho(A)$ is the next largest positive root
$p_s = p_0 + s\cdot (p_1-p_0) = (1-s)\cdot p_0 + s\cdot p_1$ for $s\in [0,1]$
where $p_0(x)\gt 0$ for $x \gt \rho(A)$ and $p_1(x)\gt 0$ for $x\gt \lambda_1$, $\lambda_1$ is a simple root, hence $p_1(x) \lt  0$ for $x\in (\lambda_2,\lambda_1)$

Suppose $\lambda_2$ has even multiplicity $m$, with $m=2$ in particular as our Base Case.  This means $p_1\big([\lambda_2-\delta, \lambda_2+\delta]\big)\leq 0$, with equality only at $\lambda_2$, for some $\delta \gt 0$ -- otherwise $p_1\big( (\lambda_2, \lambda_1)\big)\gt 0$ and combining this with $p_1(x)\gt 0$ for $x\gt \lambda_1$ would mean $\lambda_1$ has even degree.  Then for $s \in (1-\epsilon,1 )$ for any $\epsilon \gt 0$ small enough
$p_s\big(\lambda_2 - \delta\big)\lt 0$  and $p_s\big(\lambda_2 + \delta\big)\lt 0$  but $p_s\big(\lambda_2\big)\gt 0$ so Intermediate Value Theorem tells us there now at least two distinct roots $\in \big(\lambda-\delta, \lambda+\delta\big)$.  In particular with $m=2$ there are exactly two simple real roots in a neighborhood of $\lambda_2$ and we now call the largest of these $\lambda_2$ (I prefer $\lambda_2^{(s)}$ but that isn't the authors' convention).  For the inductive case i.e. even $m\geq 4$ we see  $p_s$ has some finite number $\geq 2$ of distinct real roots in neighborhood of $\lambda_2$ and again re-label the largest one of these $\lambda_2$.  This (re-labeled) $\lambda_2$ is either of odd degree or of even degree $\leq m-2$, so by strong induction hypothesis we may perturb $s$ finitely many times to recover a new $\lambda_2$ of odd degree.

Thus page 753 runs the same except line 6 says "Thus, $\lambda_1$ is simple and $\lambda_2 \lt \lambda_1$. The root $\lambda_2$ can be considered **of odd degree**, or we otherwise replace the matrix $B=A_1$ with the matrix $A_s$ for some $s$ close enough to $1$... The updated matrices possess the same properties: the rank of their difference is still not greater than $1$, and $B$ has two real eigenvalues greater than $\rho(A)$.  It is so because $\rho(A)$ changes continuously with the matrix and so **does** $\lambda_1$ **as a simple root of** $p_1$. **As for** $\lambda_2$ **the Argument Principle (/Rouche) tells us that the interior (/bounded component) of** $\gamma(t) = \lambda_2 + r\cdot\exp\big(2\pi i \cdot t\big)$ **for** $t\in[0,1]$ **for** $r\gt 0$ **small enough  has the same number of roots with multiplicity for** $p_1$ **and the characteristic polynomial** $q$ **of** $B+\Delta$ **whenever** $\Delta$**'s components are small enough, and since the multiplicity of** $\lambda_2$ **is odd, and non-real roots must come in conjugate pairs, this means there is at least one real root in a r-neighborhood of** $\lambda_2$ **and we re-label the largest of these real roots in such neighborhood as** $\lambda_2$."   The rest of the proof of Theorem 1 finishes identically.

Comment: The above should be viewed as an alternative approach to the 2nd paragraph on the page marked #753 in the pdf contained here: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/277679399_Rank-One_Corrections_of_Nonnegative_Matrices_With_an_Application_to_Matrix_Population_Models

Comment: Thanks a lot for the arguments, it's a high detail proof which I'm going to think about it. I also wrote to the authors, since I wanted to know what they had in mind to not justify this sentence and the one after with $+\Delta$ matrix.

Comment: by the way, in the spirit of rank-one corrections, I suggest setting making $\Delta$ proportional to the ones matrix i.e. $\Delta_k:= \frac{1}{k}\mathbf {11}^T$ and the desired result holds for any $k\in \mathbb N$ large enough.  (This also sets you up for an easy application of Hurwitz Theorem if you prefer using that to Rouche though it's essentially the same argument.)

Comment: But $\Delta_k$ you defined is not totally positive, i.e determinant of minors different from zero(?)

Comment: I had wondered if there was a linguistic issue in the intended meaning of "totally" here.  The minors of $\Delta$ play no role in the finish of the proof.  I.e. any $\Delta$ with all entries positive (and small enough) implies $A+\Delta$ and $B+\Delta$ are positive so Perron theory can be used and the proof of Theorem 1 finishes as is.  I suppose this is similar to my inclination to get $\lambda_2$ to have odd multiplicity as opposed to multiplicity of 1-- the weaker condition works just fine.